# mysqli functions and external classes

Tags: php, function, mysqli

Im trying to write a function that uses an external db class but its not going so well. The class works fine when its not in a function. Heres my code:

```
require_once('MysqliDb.php');


function add_post($userid,$body,$cat_id,$user_link){ 

$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_database');

$date = new DateTime();
$now = $date->getTimestamp();

$insertData = array(
   'user_id' => $userid,
    'body' => $body,
    'stamp' => $now,
    'cat_id' => $cat_id,
    'link' => $user_link
);

if ( $Db->insert('posts', $insertData) ) echo 'success!';


}
```

Heres the call:

```
$userid = 1;
$body = "hey whats up this is from a db class";
$cat_id = 3;
$user_link = "http://www.aol.com";
add_post($userid,$body,$cat_id,$user_link);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call an Object inside of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889848/call-an-object-inside-of-a-function)

Comment: $Db->insert should be $db->insert. Vars are case sensitive. Or is this just a typo in the post?

Comment: No you were right, that was it!!! such a dumb mistake, THANKS!!!